# how to insert value from drop down into mysql query to retrive data from data base

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, html

i have to choose city from drop down table and according to value i have to further retrive person belong to that city using jquery
my code is

```
 <select class="form-control" id="personCity">
            <option class="form-control" value="">Person country</option>
            <option class="form-control" value="usa">usa</option>
            <option class="form-control" value="aus">Australia/option>
</select>
```

i have to get the value using jquery

```
$('#personCity').change(function(e) {
   var personCity=$('#personCity').val();
   $('#personcityRetrive').text(personCity);
});
```

and in database i have following data

```
country     person
 usa           abc
 aus           xyz
 usa           123
 aus           ABC
```

mysql code is

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM outlets WHERE country='" 
?><span id="personcityRetrive"></span> 
<?php "'");?>
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server before the html and javascript is ever sent to the browser. Javascript runs on the browser. The only way to do what you're wanting is using an Ajax call to return to the server to get the data. Then send the response back to the browser and insert the response in the div. Check out a tutorial on doing ajax with PHP. Try it yourself and if you have problems post your code here in another question for help. http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/learning-how-to-use-jquery-ajax-with-php-video-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Given this HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="personCity">
    <option class="form-control" value="">Person country</option>
    <option class="form-control" value="usa">usa</option>
    <option class="form-control" value="aus">Australia/option>
</select>
```

You need to perform AJAX when the change happens. The JQuery:

```
$('#personCity').change(function(e) {
    var personCity=$('#personCity').val();
    $.get('lookupCity.php', { "city": personCity }, function(result){
        $("#personcityRetrive").html(result);
    });
});
```

Your PHP will need to stand alone (`lookupCity.php`), connect to the SQL Server, and echo the result of a SQL Lookup. It should not use MySQL functions, these are deprecated. Also you want to avoid SQL Injection. Try this:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT person FROM outlets WHERE country=? LIMIT 1");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_GET['city']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $person);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    printf("%s\n", $person);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```